# How to run Spring Boot Application without manual activation?

Tags: html, spring-boot, intellij-idea, localhost

I have this web application that heavily relies on API endpoints for its functionality. When I try opening the HTML file that displays the login/registration page and attempts to log in a returning user or register for a new account, this error is shown:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/Login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The application will only work if the spring boot application is running in IntelliJ:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Is there a way for my web application to properly connect with the API, without manually having to run the code shown above every time in IntelliJ?